# Can an infinitive be the object of a preposition?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, diagramming

```
"I found a place for Tom and Stacy to live."
```

I first thought that the prepositional phrase "for Tom and Stacy" and the infinitive "to live" were separate phrases both modifying "place".

Is it possible that "Tom and Stacy to live" is one infinitive phrase with Tom and Stacy as its subject acting as the object of the preposition for?

Comment: In all honesty I have never studied English grammar in sufficient detail as to be able to parse prepositional phrases, and I would think that few native speakers like me have. All I can tell you is that the entire sentence is perfectly grammatical, and in everyday use.

Comment: Both _for_ and _to_ are part of the infinitive complementizer. That is, they're not meaning-bearing; they're part of the grammar machinery. Infinitives are clauses, with verbs and subjects of the verbs. _For_ goes (mostly optionally) in front of the subject of an infinitive clause, and _to_ goes (mostly obligatorily) in front of its verb phrase. Since infinitives usually don't have subjects, _for_ is rare, except at the beginning of a sentence: _For her to see it would be a good idea_ is OK, but not **Her to see it would be a good idea*.

Comment: @John Lawler So you're saying that "tom and stacy" *is* the subject of the infinitive, but for is not acting as a preposition but as a grammatical particle, an "infinitve complementizer"?

Comment: Yes. Just like _to_ is doing. The infinitive _to_ is more common because there's always a verb but frequently not a subject. That's one interpretation. chasty gives another, benefactive, interpretation in the answer below. In fact, the two readings mean the same thing; they're just two different ways to arrange the same ideas.

Answer (score 1):

> I found a place for Tom and Stacy to live.

You can invert this:

*'I found a place  to live for Tom and Stacy.'*

It's just an abbreviated form of

*'I found a place (in which to live) for Tom and Stacy.'*

The phrase '[in which] to live' is adjectival and modifies 'place'.

Comment: That's another reading; _for_ can mark a  benefactive phrase.

Comment: "I found for Tom and Stacey a place for them to live."  The first "for" is benefactive "for", and the the second "for" is the first part of the for-to complementizer.

Comment: @JohnLawler - I've been calling these compound verb complement phrases, in this case a vc in an object relation (O), where complement is simply defined as a phrase that adds meaning to another word phrase. In the parse, capitals mean the phrase is core syntax, lower case means non core. Non core could be removed without changing the meaning of the core. 1. I found a place for Tom and Stacy to live. S|V|O[NP + nc(pp:pre+nfc):place] 2. I found a place to live for Tom and Stacy. S|V|O[NP + nc(vp + rvc(pp):place] In 2. - the vc (pp) is required because it without it the subject of to live is *I*.

Answer (score 1):

We still strictly follow the grammatical rules in identifying the elements comprising that sentence.

First, the answer to your question

"Is it possible that "Tom and Stacy to live" is one infinitive phrase with Tom and Stacy as its subject acting as the object of the preposition for?"

is "no".

Please take note that no circumstances must you say that the object of a preposition (in this case "Tom and Stacy") can be a subject. An object of a preposition is always in objective case. Therefore, "for Tom and Stacy" is an adjectival phrase separate from the infinitive "to live".

Now, the question is, 'What are the elements that correspond to both "for Tom and Stacy" and "to live"?'

1. "for Tom and Stacy" is an adjectival phrase (prepositional phrase) modifying the noun phrase "a place".
2. "to live" is a full infinitive functioning as an adjective that modifies also the noun phrase "a place".

How to prove my answer?

Assuming that the sentence is in this form:

"I found a place to live."

This shows that "to live" is indeed modifying  the noun phrase "a place". Adding another modifier "for Tom and Stacy" will not change the function of "to live".

Comment: Welcome to ELU, please add a source (for the grammatical rules you refer to) to support your answer.

Comment: Hello! https://www.grammar-monster.com  and other grammar-related sites. :)

Answer (score 0):

A infinitive can have a logical subject as in the construction "for + object + to-infinitive.

- He gestured for her to follow.

Meaning: His gesture meant she should follow him. The word group "for her to follow him" is a group that belongs together. I think this construction is a specialty of English.

Your example with "for Tom and Stacy to live" is equivalent to "I found  a place that Tom and Stacy can live in".